# Is the word "several" fits here?

Tags: word-usage

In *Braveheart (1995)*, Hamish watches two runners running through hillside:

> Hamish: William! It's **several** runners!

Two runners approaches Wallace and his band:

> Runner 1: The English are advancing an army toward Stirling.
>
> Wallace: Do the nobles rally?
>
> Runner 2: Robert the Bruce and most of the others will not commit to
> battle, but word has spread, and the Highlanders are coming  down on
> their own.

If there are only two runners, so several means more than two, so word **several** fits here?

Comment: Is it possible that Hamish hasn't seen the runners clearly enough to count them accurately (or that he thinks that there might be more following the first two)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaken, he doesn't say "several".

He says:

> William, it's our runners.

The Scottish accent makes the word "our" into two distinct syllables (ow-er). Some other British English accents pronounce it similarly, although a little less obviously; others with one syllable (similar to the word 'are'). This, along with the accent may have contributed to your mistake.

---

You are correct that "several" means more than two, but not many.

Comment: I am not mistaken, pretty sure it's **several**, That's why I approached this site.